# How do I escape single quotes in variables in a Solr DataImportHandler?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have a DataImportHandler for importing data from a SQL database.  The root entity, `Foo` has many `Bar`s.  The `Bar` table uses `Foo.Name` as its foreign key.  Some Foo names have single quotes in them--such as `STW's`.

The import query for the `Bar` entity is something like:

```
select name from Bar where Foo_Name = ${Foo.Name}
```

However, when Foo.Name contains a single quote the import fails with a SQL exception of `Incorrect syntax near 's`.

I've tried wrapping the parameter with `escapeSql(${Foo.Name})` but it doesn't appear to be called--the sql being executed is `where Foo_Name = 'escapeSql(STW's)'`

How do I properly escape the `Foo.Name` to avoid issues when they contain single-quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
Foo_Name = '${escapeSql(Foo.Name)}'
```

since `escapeSql` is a solr function and not a normal sql function.